# str.replace function with parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I don't know how to use the "replace" python string function to remove brackets.

i assume i'm doing something wrong here - i have this code:

```
line = line.replace('\(','A')
```

which, when faced with a string that has a `(` in it doesn't do anything. I've also tried

```
line = line.replace('\\(','A')
```

but no dice there either.

I know that the function works - (this is for converting sqlite data dump to mysql and seriously why hasn't someone made a $10 app to do this? I would have bought it by now.) - because i can do

```
line = line.replace('CREATE','A')
```

and i get all the create statements replaced by the letter A...

What am i missing here?

Comment: You tagged this as `regex` but you don't use regular expressions in your code.

Comment: i uh, i thought i was using regex... am i not?

Comment: @Matthias: That's the crux of the problem here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't escape it?

```
line = line.replace('(', 'A')
```

`str.replace` doesn't use regular expressions. That's what the `re.sub` function does.

Comment: oh lord i'm an idiot - i thought i had to escape it or else have a regex problem with brackets... thankyou!